# Find optimized threshold value

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, optimization, feature-engineering

I have a dataset which has a `fraud_label` and some other sets of feature variable. How can I find the best rule which would help me identify `fraud_label` correctly with the best precision and recall values. Example of features are `number_of_site_visits, external_fraud_score etc.` I need to be able to come up with a rule which says that if `number_of_site_visits` is less than X and `external_fraud_score` is greater than Y then we will get the best precision and recall. I have to do this in Python and any help you can provide or direction would be very helpful.

I have tried Random Forest model but that gives me feature importances and not exact threshold values.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to find the best rule for identifying fraud_label correctly with the best precision and recall values is to use a supervised machine learning algorithm such as logistic regression or support vector machines. These algorithms can be used to train a model on your dataset and then use the trained model to predict the fraud_label. The model can then be evaluated using metrics such as precision and recall.

You can also use grid search or cross-validation to find the optimal parameters for your model, which will help you identify the best thresholds for each feature variable. This will allow you to create a rule that will give you the best precision and recall values.

In Python, you can use scikit-learn library for implementing these algorithms.